# vuetify dropdown get data's by using vue Infinite loading

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, infinite-scroll

I tried to get data for my vuetify drop down list by using vue-infinite-loading. function is not calling automatically. 
Below is my code

```
        <v-menu offset-y offset-x bottom left max-height="500" min-width="400" max-width="450">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <el-badge :value="unReadMessage" :hidden="hidden" class="item">
                    <v-icon color="white" v-on="on">notifications</v-icon>
                </el-badge>
            </template>
            <v-list v-for="(item, index) in notification_data" :key="index">
                <v-list-tile>
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                        <v-list-tile-title>{{item.title}}</v-list-tile-title>
                        <v-list-tile-sub-title>{{item.description}}</v-list-tile-sub-title>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                </v-list-tile>
            </v-list>
            <infinite-loading :identifier="infiniteId" @infinite="infiniteHandler"  ref="infiniteLoading"></infinite-loading>
        </menu>
```

Below is written in script. I already imported this "import InfiniteLoading from 'vue-infinite-loading';"
When i put the infinite loader out of the menu, its working but it shown the value out of the list

```
    <script>
       methods: {
                infiniteHandler($state) {
                    this.loading = true;
                    this.axios.get(api, {
                        params: {
                            page: this.page,
                        },
                    })
                        .then(({data}) => {
                            if (data.next !== null) {
                                this.page += 1;
                                this.notification_data = this.notification_data.concat(data.results);
                                this.loading = false;
                                $state.loaded();
                            }
                            else {
                                this.loading = false;
                                this.notification_data = this.notification_data.concat(data.results);
                                $state.complete();
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            this.$notify({
                                type: 'error',
                                title: 'Error!',
                                message: error,
                            });
                        });
                },
       },
       components: {
         InfiniteLoading
       }
    </script>
```